# http-server not going to public directory

Tags: npm, httpserver

I have installed the basic http-server (https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server) and it works okay however, I cannot get:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

to default at ./public directory.

When I use:

```
myapp MyUser$ http-server ./public
```

It returns a not found error.

If I simply use:

```
myapp MyUser$ http-server
```

It returns a listing of all my subdirectories and I have to manually navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080/http-server/public/
```

to get my index page.

How can I get the public directory to run?

Answer (score 0):

Before you try this, try setting the server files root to http-server (if you can, I don't use NPM). If this does not work, then I'm sorry but I can't fix your problem.

```
myapp MyUser$ http-server/public
```